# Expected number of coin flips before a player's total score reaches $3$

Tags: probability

> there is a simple game using number of coins.
>        initially, player has score 0 and is given three number of coins. then he flips all his coins at once.
>        the number of coins showed head will be added to his score.
>        if player scored 1, he will do the next flip, with only 2 coins, scoring rules are same.
>        if player scored 2, he will do the next flip with only one coin and scoring rules are same.
>        if player scored 3, he won.
>        ...
>        so, a player with score s will flip (3-s) coins, and with number of coins showed head being added to score, until his total score
>   reaches 3.
>        what is expected number of flips in this game?

I think this 'expected number of flips' is confusing me.

let's say his current score is 2. he can score 1 with probability of 0.5. therefore expected number of flips to win his game is 2.

let's say his current score is 1. he can score 1 with probability of 0.5 and score 2 with probability of 0.25. Now it's where I'm stuck. if he wants to score 1+1 and win the game, the probability is 0.5*0.5 - which means 4 more turns are expected to win the game in such scoring combination. if he wants to score 2 and win the game, the probability is 0.25, which means also 4 more turns are expected to win the game by flipping two coins and scoring two heads. I don't really know what else to do here.

Comment: The game does not seem fully defined. (1( What happens if we get $0$ heads on a turn? Prsumably we flip again, same conditions. (2) Do we count number of flips, so $3$ for first round, or do we count the number of rounds? (3) What happens if we go "over," that is, jump from $2$ to $4$?

Comment: 1) if you get 0 heads, flip again. 2) number of round. 3) we can't go over, since we're flipping (3-s) coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a general-purpose approach. At any time, our score (State) is $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$. Let $a$ be the expected number of **additional** rounds needed if we are in State $0$, $b$ be the expected number of additional rounds needed if we are in State $1$, and $c$ the expected number of additional rounds needed if we are in State $2$. We only want to find $a$, but $b$ and $c$ will be useful.

Suppose we are in State $0$. Flip. This has a cost of $1$ (round). With probability $\frac{1}{8}$ we get $0$ heads. Then we stay in State $0$, and our expected number of additional rounds needed is $a$. With probability $\dfrac{3}{8}$ we get $1$ head, and enter State $1$, and our expected number of additional rounds becomes $b$. With probability $\dfrac{3}{8}$ we get $2$ heads, and enter State $2$, with expected additional rounds needed equal to $c$. Finally, with probability $\dfrac{1}{8}$ the game is over, no additional rounds needed. We have obtained the equation
$$a=1+\frac{a}{8}+\frac{3b}{8}+\frac{3c}{8}.$$

Suppose we are in State $1$. Flip (cost, $1$ round). With probability $\dfrac{1}{4}$, we remain in State $1$, and the expected number of additional rounds needed is $b$. With probability $\dfrac{2}{4}$ we enter State $2$, and the expected number of additional rounds needed is $c$. With probability $\dfrac{1}{4}$ the game is over. So 
$$b=1+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{2c}{4}.$$

Finally, suppose we are in State $c$. The same reasoning shows that 
$$c=1+\frac{c}{2}.$$

It is almost obvious that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are finite. Under the assumption that they are, to find $a$, $b$, and $c$ we only need to solve a simple system of $3$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns.

Comment: thank you. It wasn't obvious for me when I started thinking about this, but after your explanation it is crystal clear. It is used to solve this: http://projecteuler.net/problem=323

Comment: @thkang: For a variant of your coin problem in which the numbers are very large, one might have to use efficient techniques to solve the linear algebra problem. There is a huge amount of theoretical and practical work that deals with Markov chains and their transition probabilities.